# How can you change the center of gravity while keeping the center of origin as is?

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

How can you change the **center of gravity** while keeping the **center of origin** *as is*?

This question is different to the previous version by another user.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: That's ridiculous! That makes it more complicated then to realistically animate falling objects.